# "Status" field in /proc/net/wireless

Tags: linux, bash, networking

I trying to check if any wireless interfaces are UP with a bash script. I think I can do this by checking the Status field in /proc/net/wireless for every interface. However, I tried to look for up reference to the possible values in that field and what they mean, and nothing seems to come up. Does anyone know? Is this the ideal way to approach this problem?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with wireless interfaces, but couldn't you use `ifconfig` or `iwconfig` and grep for UP or something?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to check the `operstate` of each interface to tell if it is either; up, down or unknown. Here's one way using `GNU awk`:

```
awk '{ split(FILENAME, array, "/"); print array[5] ": " $1 }' $(find /sys/class/net/*/operstate ! -type d)
```

On my system, here's some results:

```
eth0: up
lo: unknown
vboxnet0: down
wlan0: up
```

---

To check for wireless interfaces only, you will need to check for a folder called 'wireless' under each interface. Here's one way using `GNU awk`.

```
awk -F "/" 'FNR==NR { wire[$5]++; next } { split(FILENAME, state, "/"); if (state[5] in wire && $1 == "up") print state[5] }' <(find /sys/class/net/*/wireless -type d) $(find /sys/class/net/*/operstate ! -type d)
```

Results:

```
wlan0
```

Pseudo-code:

```
1. Get the directory names of the wireless devices as the 1st argument
2. Split these names on the "/" delimiter
3. Add the 5th column (the name of the wireless device) to an array called 'wire'
4. Now read in the operstates of all network interfaces as the 2nd argument
5. Split the interface filenames on the "/" delimiter to an array called 'state'
6. If the interface is a wireless interface (i.e. if it's in the array called
   wire) and its operstate is "up", print it.
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems like a step in the right direction. However, doesn't the second and third awk statement that only returns wireless interface dependent on the name of all wireless interfaces starting with "wlan"? It's very possible that this would be the case in many situations, right?

Comment: @timtran: I've deleted the second and third awk statements because wireless interfaces may be named with strange characters. In my testing, I've found that each wireless interface should contain a directory called 'wireless'. The edited code above checks this and only returns wireless interface names if they are "up". Please see the pseudocode. HTH.